# Application of law of total probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the discrete random variables $X,Z,W$ with supports $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Z}, \mathcal{W}$ respectively. Let $\mathcal{W}\equiv \{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$.

Take any $x\in \mathcal{X}, z\in \mathcal{Z}$. Is the following relation correct
$$
Pr(X=x, Z=z)=\\Pr(X=x| Z=z, W\in \{w_1,w_2\})\times Pr(Z=z, W\in \{w_1,w_2\}) +\\Pr(X=x| Z=z, W=w_3)\times Pr(Z=z, W=w_3)
$$

---

I believe that the expression is correct. In fact:

$$
Pr(X=x, Z=z)=\\\overbrace{Pr(X=x, Z=z, W\in \{w_1,w_2\})}^{Pr(X=x, Z=z, W=w_1)+Pr(X=x, Z=z, W=w_2)}+Pr(X=x, Z=z, W=w_3)\\=Pr(X=x| Z=z, W\in \{w_1,w_2\})\times Pr(Z=z, W\in \{w_1,w_2\}) +\\Pr(X=x| Z=z, W=w_3)\times Pr(Z=z, W=w_3)
$$

Comment: Your equation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Law of Total Probability applies to any partitioning of the support.  That's actually the definition, with partitions of sets of single values just being a particular case.

So...

Take any $A,B$ such that $A\subseteq\mathcal X$ and $B\subseteq\mathcal Z$.  Partition $\mathcal W$ into $\{C,D\}$ (so $\mathcal W=C\cup D$ and $C\cap D=\emptyset$ as per definition of a partition).  Then the additive property of probability of disjoint unions, and definition of conditional probability, states that:

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{\in}A, Z{\in}B)&={{\mathsf P(X{\in }A,Z{\in}B, W{\in}C)}+{\mathsf P(X{\in}A,Z{\in}B, W{\in}D)}}\\[1ex]&={{\mathsf P(X{\in}A\mid Z{\in}B,W{\in}C)\cdot\mathsf P(Z{\in}B, W{\in}C)}+{\mathsf P(X{\in}A\mid Z{\in}B,W{\in}D)\cdot\mathsf P(Z{\in}B, W{\in}D)}}\end{align}$

---

You have taken $A=\{x\}$, $B=\{z\}$ and the partition of $\{\{w_1,w_2\},\{w_3\}\}$, so indeed:

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}x, Z{=}z)&={{\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Z{=}z,W{\in}\{w_1,w_2\})\cdot\mathsf P(Z{=}z, W{\in}\{w_1,w_2\})}+{\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Z{=}z,W{=}w_3)\cdot\mathsf P(Z{=}z, W{=}w_3)}}\end{align}$